# shared linking against libB.so, libB.so.3, or libB.so.3.0?

Tags: linker, dynamic-linking, abi

Suppose I would like to create a library A that links against another (system) library B of which the following files are installed:

```
$ ll /usr/lib/libB*
libB.so -> libB.so.3
libB.so.3 -> libB.so.3.0
libB.so.3.0
```

When creating my own `libA.so*`, I suppose it'd be good practice to include any of `libB.so*` on the link line. In fact, the linker flag `-Wl,--no-undefined` even enforces this.

It doesn't seem to make a difference which of the above `libB` files are used for linking since eventually they all point to the same file `libB.so.3.0`, but I'm guessing there are best practices for this, too.

What's recommended and why?

Answer (score 1):

> What's recommended and why?

Only linking against `libB.so` is officially supported. Linking against `libB.so.3` or `libB.so.3.0` works more or less by accident; don't do it.

You can read about external library versioning [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-0690/chapter5-5/index.html).

Comment: The first sentence in your reference reads: "Runtime references to a shared object should always refer to the versioned file name." -- This sounds like I should link to `libB.so.3`.

Comment: @Nico: "This sounds like I should link to libB.so.3" -- no it doesn't. Read the document *again*. Pay special attention to `SONAME`. When you link to `libB.so`, **if** it has `SONAME`, the linker will record `libB.so.3` in the dynamic section of your executable automatically.